# scrollToRow(...animated:false) causes a glitch

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to build an UI for chat/messenger purposes. It is based on `UITableView` with dynamic cells and I am trying to adopt simple behaviours from WhatsApp/Native Messages App like when you enter chatting page it should show the end of list etc...

I am using after `tableView.reloadData()` to show user the latest message.

```
func scrollToBottom(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(
            row: self.numberOfRows(inSection:  self.numberOfSections-1) - 1,
            section: self.numberOfSections - 1)
        if self.hasRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath) {
            self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine as it is. However I want this scroll stuff to be not animated. So when set the `animated` parameter as `false` it directly starts from the bottom end of list but then slightly jumps upwards as in small couple leaps.

I tried to call `scrollToRow` inside `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` however no luck there. Nothing else I came up with or found to try.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Interestingly [this person](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118559) seems to be having the same problem but only when it _is_ animated.

Comment: @Sweeper yeah I saw that thread as well. unfortunately it is unresolved

Comment: I actually cannot reproduce. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @Sweeper I will be back with that.

Comment: @Sweeper Interestingly I cant reproduce the problem neither. I cant share the problematic code because it is under NDA and I should also share the whole project with you to reproduce it. Also the problem did not happened again as I explained however It still shows have two problems. There has been some visible movement which I can reproduce here  https://gist.github.com/mrfarukturgut/db8ba518088440b2b61362f0a1d21d28 and it just does not scroll exact bottom including insets which I could not reproduce

Comment: I still try to reproduce the problems together and I will share it with you

Comment: @Sweeper I fixed the scrolling exact end issue luckily. There is a UIStackView inside some cell classes and some of them would not layout properly. I fixed the layout issue and now there is only one problem which initially you can see the top of the list for a moment and then it goes to the bottom. The link has the same issue. If you wanna still help, I will be really appreciated.

Comment: I have same issue, and i don't have any stack views...